# How to periodically poll some value using Java (Swing)?

Tags: java

I am using swing based model.My form contains one Jbutton its called "polling(function name is getvalue())".I have a function name as "getvalue()".This function does retrieve values(this value will change after some span of time) and print it in console. I want code and idea about, that function will call automatically every 5 minutes ( or some span of time interval)and retrieve values and print it in console.I want code using timer concept .

my button function is like

private void ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

}

where will write my Automatic polling code.

Comment: This is a dupe of the question you posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335129/help-me-sir-java-based.

Comment: sounds like homework. also -1 for atrocious grammar.

Comment: Hey, give the poor guy a break. Maybe English isn't his first language. I'm sure his English is better than my Urdu.

Comment: @Adamski, that link seems to be a 404 for me.

Answer (score 1):

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

> A Swing timer (an instance of
> `javax.swing.Timer`) fires one or more
> action events after a specified delay.
> Don't confuse Swing timers with the
> general-purpose timer facility that
> was added to the java.util package in
> release 1.3. This page describes only
> Swing timers.
>
> In general, we recommend
> using Swing timers rather than
> general-purpose timers for GUI-related
> tasks because Swing timers all share
> the same, pre-existing timer thread
> and the GUI-related task automatically
> executes on the event-dispatch thread.
> However, you might use a
> general-purpose timer if you don't
> plan on touching the GUI from the
> timer, or need to perform lengthy
> processing.